# Catching Errors with Google Classroom API

Tags: google-classroom

What's the right way to catch errors using the Google Classroom API?

I'm trying to do something like:

```
gapi.client.classroom.courses.list({
  pageSize: 100
}).then((response) => {
  return process(response);
});
```

But if a Google user who doesn't have a Classroom account executes this code, it throws an error, and I'm unclear on how to catch/handle it.

I've tried wrapping this block of code with a `try {...} catch(error) {...}` and that doesn't catch it.  I've also tried adding a `.catch(function(error){ ... });` after then `.then()` statement and that also doesn't seem to work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The answer is here:
https://developers.google.com/api-client-library/javascript/features/promises

The `.then` call takes two arguments.  The first is a function invoked on success, and the second is a function invoked on failure:

```
.then(
  function(response) {
    return process(response);
  },
  function(errorResponse) {
    return handleError(errorResponse);
  }
);
```